# Multiplying floats and keep/get double precision accuracy

Tags: c++, casting, floating-point, precision

I have a function that takes floats, I'm doing some computation with them, and I'd like to keep as much accuracy as possible in the returned result. I read that when you multiply two floats, you double the number of significant digits.

So when two floats get multiplied, for example `float e, f;` and I do `double g = e * f`, when do the bits get truncated?

In my example function below, do I need casting, and if yes, where? This is in a tight inner loop, if I put `static_cast<double>(x)` around each variable `a b c d` where it's used, I get 5-10% slowdown. But I suspect I don't need to cast each variable separately, and only in some locations, if at all? Or does returning a double here do not give me any gain anyway and I can as well just return a float?

```
double func(float a, float b, float c, float d) {
    return (a - b) * c + (a - c) * b;
}
```

Comment: You only need one cast as the other operands will be converted for you _"if either operand is double, the other operand is converted to double"_ source:   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions  However this will still give you the same slowdown.  The 2nd question about returning a double depends on what you do with the returned result.

Comment: Yes, but in my case, both (all) operands (except for the return type) are floats?

Comment: You might get better performance (and better accuracy anyway) if you use `double` everywhere. This saves you the conversion overhead.

Comment: @5gon12eder - "get better performance (and better accuracy anyway) if you use double everywhere"  ... don't  forget the: "at the expense of RAM consumption" price tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you multiply two floats without casting, the result is calculated with float precision (i.e. truncated) and then converted to double.

To calculate the result in double, you need to cast at least one operand to double first. Then the entire calculation will be done in double (and all float values will be converted). However, that will create the same slowdown. The slowdown is likely because converting a number from float to double is not entirely trivial (different bit size and range of exponent and mantisa).

If I'd be doing that and have control over the function definition, I'd pass all the arguments as double (I generally use double everywhere, on modern computers the speed difference between calculating in float vs double is negligible, only issues could be memory throughput and cache performance when operating on large arrays of values).

Btw. the case important for precision actually isn't the multiplication, but the addition/subtraction - that is where the precision can make a big difference. Consider adding/subtracting 1e+6 and 1e-3.

Comment: Thank you, your first three sentences perfectly answer my question! And the other information is quite useful as well.

Answer (score 4):

Meaning is more important than 5-10% slowdown. What I'd do:

```
double func_impl(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    return (a - b) * c + (a - c) * b;
}

double func(float a, float b, float c, float d) {
    return func_impl(a, b, c, d);
}
```

I'd choose this even if it's a bit slower, because it expresses the idea that you want double precision in your calculations well and just need the floats on the interface; while it keeps the body of your function separate from the casting (the latter being done in one step).